# Python: How to access outer class namespaces

Tags: python, namespaces

Consider this code:

```
class A:
        B = 42  # or whatever
        class C:
                a = B  # wont find `B` here
```

That will not work because in `class C`, it wont find `B`.

You also cannot use `A.B` because also `A` is not known at this point because it is still being constructed and thus it is not in the global namespace. Inside a member function, that would work because at the point when you execute that code, the global name `A` is probably registered. However, I'm explicitly asking for the direct access, not inside a member function.

So, is there any other way in such nested class constructs to access the outer namespaces?

I guess the answer might be no, or at least not in a clean way. I added a `print(locals())` inside of `class C` and with Python 2, I get `{'__module__': '__main__'}`, with Python 3, I get `{'__qualname__': 'A.C', '__module__': '__main__'}`. So neither the locals nor the globals will give me the access to the parent local namespace.

About a non-clean way: `sys._getframe(1).f_locals["B"]` will work. That are the locals of class `A` while it is being constructed, and `B` is in there.

So, if there is no clean way to do that, what are other solutions? I could declare all classes directly in the global namespace but I don't like that (for my specific use case). I could move them into a submodule and import them in `A`. But that makes the code more complicated to read. Any other solutions?

---

So, I guess it's always the same, unless I don't show a real-world example, people will not believe how such a use-case can happen. So, here it is ([via](https://github.com/albertz/PyCPython)):

```
class structs:
    # .... many more

    class _anonymous_label(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ('lb_type', ctypes.c_int),
            ('lb_str', ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_byte))]

    class _anonymous_labellist(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ('ll_nlabels', ctypes.c_int),
            ('ll_label', ctypes.POINTER(_anonymous_label))]  # error

    # .... many more
```

Comment: Seeing how the example is trivial: what use case do you have where this is not trivial?

Comment: I'm actually a bit curious.  How is that different from a closure?  Where the inner function has access to the outer scope?  I played around with using a metaclass and using its **\__new\__** to set C.a =B, but even that was choking - *global name 'B' is not defined*.  I do realize a class declaration is not a function per se, but the scoping aspect "looks the same".  Also, didn't Python 3 (I'm on 2) change nesting scope lookups?

Comment: `class structs: ...` - why would you do that? Even if you want the classes in there to be in their own namespace, that's a job for the module system, not nested classes. Make a `structs` module.

Comment: @JLPeyret: It's the same as with methods, which don't look in the class for variable lookup. Scopes nested inside a class scope never look in the class scope for variable lookup.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Got it. Need **self** or class name.  Not so odd then.

Comment: @user2357112: That's what I meant by "I could move them into a submodule".

Comment: @Albert: And that's exactly what you should do. Classes are not mini-modules, and making another module doesn't significantly impact readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Constants:
    a = 1

class A:
    class B(Constants):
        pass

    class C(Constants):
        pass

print(A.B.a, A.C.a)
```

Comment: They don't share the same base constants. In my example, it was just by accident that the attribute name was the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'd perform the class variable assignments for the inner classes in the outer class *after* the inner class declarations are complete. It's very little more complicated, completely obvious and it works:

```
class A:
    class B:
        a = 1
    class C:
        pass
    C.a = B.a

print(A.B.a, A.C.a)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that wont work for my case because the class construction needs to be finished (because it's `ctypes.Structure`). Also, code editors wont like that when the member attribute is defined outside.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about

```
var = 1
class A:
    class B:
        a = var
    class C:
        a = var
```

Comment: I need to reference `B`, not a common constant global like `var`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always work with temporary objects which you don't expose. Depending on how your non-trivial example looks, this may not be appropriate, however.

```
# foo module
ABC_ATTRIBUTE = 42
class A:
  B = ABC_ATTRIBUTE
  class C:
    a = ABC_ATTRIBUTE
del ABC_ATTRIBUTE  # no longer accessible as foo.ABC_ATTRIBUTE
```

Comment: That is what I meant when I said "I could declare all classes directly in the global namespace".

Comment: @Albert I see, your added example makes it clear why you don't want that. I don't get the need for `class struct`, but that doesn't change the problem you want solved.

Comment: Because I don't want all the members to be in the global namespace. As in your example, I could have a big list of `del xy` at the end but that seems like a bit ugly solution.

Comment: @Albert Yeah, for your case the `del` is *very* ugly, I agree. But having `class struct` just for a namespace - I'd use a submodule for that, since that's what it effectively is. Not to mention that this avoids problems with python versions that don't have `__qualname__` yet.